Calling python package by package name
I want to call my local package utility by its name like in Django django-admin. It has structure like: utility-name [command]
I've found the method of calling utility using __ main __.py. Structure of using this method is: python -m myappname. But it isn't what I wanted.
So how I can use structure of calling like in django-admin? I'm junior programmer so if this information isn't enough u may ask questions

What operating system are you on?

django-admin is just a script in a directory to which the PATH variable refers.

Depending on how you build your project, command scripts can be auto-generated. A .toml file for instance has a project.scripts section.

While not exactly what you want, have you check out Management Commands? You call them like python manage.py {command_name} [args]. You could alias them if you’re super picky about it being 1 word- just sharing the option in case if you didn’t know about it!

@Axe319 I`m using Windows

django-admin is just a file located in a directory that belongs to the paths where the operating system will search.
Indeed, if we look at django-admin, it looks like:

#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())


and this is then located for example in ~/.local/bin/ with the operating system listing this. For Unix-like operating systems, there is normally a variable $PATH that is a colon-separated list of directories to look at. For Windows, this is a system variable named path that can be modified.
You thus make a runnable file (without .py extension, and with executable permissions for a Unix-like system), and add the directory to the PATH environment variable/system variable. Typically this will then for example load a virtual environment and trigger another script.

So as i understend when i use pip install django is adds django-admin to PATH?

@Ivan_Solaris: no, typically the bin of the "system-wide" Python is already in the PATH, and if you use  a virtual environment, it essentially manipulates the path to point to the bin directory of the environment.
